# Wire color standards for a reversible DC motor

Tags: wire, standard, color

I'm working on a project with a DC motor that runs in both directions. If the motor ran only in one direction, I'd use red/black for positive and ground, but as they reverse, there isn't a consistent positive or negative terminal. I understand that wire color isn't the most important thing, but I'm wondering if there is any standard or convention, even if it is weak.

Comment: I tend to default to orange and purple as commonly available wire colors that aren't really established standards for anything in particular, but it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: The great thing about standards is there are so many to choose from...

Comment: As in DMM probes Red=+, Blk= -  Logically you may reverse anytime depends on CW or CCW

Comment: @Hearth I was going to default to something similar if I can't find better.
TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, there's no consistent +/-, so I don't think red/black works.

Comment: Red and black should not be considered synonymous with positive and negative. This is too often not the case. A good example is in single phase wiring in the US where black and red are often the two line wires and white is the neutral. Another example is phone cable pairs where solid colors are used and none of the conductors should be considered ground since they can carry AC. I suggest using what you have at hand and not try to apply any arbitrary wiring standard that others are unlikely to understand anyway.

Comment: I would label the terminal connections and avoid mention of color. And, having worked on cars, some have a single color (black) with identification printed on the insulation, others use colors and extra stripes etc This leads to many standards with some having brown as battery positive while others use brown as the ground or battery negative.

Comment: well, red/black are pos/neg for the *forward* direction; they are actually IEC endorsed for DC supplies. The only nitpick is that being them possibly reversed there could be a cabling conundrum where someone pick your motor ground as a ground for something else. So the red/blk pair should only, in principle, for unswitched raw power supplies. It's mostly a project/customer requirement thing

Comment: Either *same colour* or non-specific, like the purple/orange suggestion. The real issue is whether the shaft turns clockwise or counter-clockwise. Then you have the problem of which end of the motor you decide is "front/back". Ugh...too many variables. Speaker-makers have an easier time (in vs. out) and often mark ONE of the leads with a polarity indicator, but don't mention which direction...useful for matching similar speakers.

Answer (score 2):

As the motor is reversible, I'd be inclined to use two wires of the same colour. This helps emphasise that you can't make any assumptions about them.

One thing I've learnt in years of engineering is that a colour scheme that's obvious to one person is anything but to another, unless it's mandated by some standard like mains wiring, where black is ground on the European side of the pond, and hot on the US side.

Comment: This is a good point. I would do this, but I'm not using keyed connectors, and so I could get the motor running opposite the intended direction.